# Git can no longer open emacs as its editor

Tags: macos, emacs, git, zsh

I'm running Git version 1.7.3.2 that I built from source, zsh is my shell, and emacs is my editor.

Recently I started seeing the following:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/git/1.7.3.2/libexec/git-core/git-sh-setup: line 106: emacs: command not found
```

Could not execute editor

My zshrc looks like the following so I can use the Cocoa build and the console binary provided with it.

```
EMACS_HOME="/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS"                                                                                                                               

function e()  { PATH=$EMACS_HOME/bin:$PATH $EMACS_HOME/Emacs -nw $@ }                                                                                                             
function ec() { PATH=$EMACS_HOME/bin:$PATH emacsclient -t $@ }                                                                                                                    

function es() { e --daemon=$1 && ec -s $1 }                                                                                                                                       
function el() { ps ax|grep Emacs }                                                                                                                                                
function ek() { $EMACS_HOME/bin/emacsclient -e '(kill-emacs)' -s $1 }                                                                                                             

function ecompile() {                                                                                                                                                             
   e -eval "(setq load-path (cons (expand-file-name \".\") load-path))" \                                                                                                         
       -batch -f batch-byte-compile $@                                                                                                                                            
}                                                                                                                                                                                 

alias emacs=e                                                                                                                                                                     
alias emacsclient=ec
```

And I also have

```
export EDITOR="emacs"
```

and have tried adding

```
export GIT_EDITOR="emacs"
```

(and swapping that out with "e")

But whatever I try I can't get git to open emacs whenever I need to do a commit or an interactive rebase, etc etc...

Comment: `which emacs`? Or maybe enter the full path to emacs in `EDITOR`?

Comment: A very recent build of Emacs 24.  And yes, a full path might be necessary...

Answer (score 2):

I needed to skip the functions built in my .zshrc and reference the full path for $GIT_EDITOR.

```
export GIT_EDITOR="/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -nw"
```